# Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10002] - MAKE SELECT WITH MAX ON HIVE

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I'm trying to execute this select to return only the most recent inserted records

i'm using HIVE

co_junta_comer and co_informacao can repeat but é need the most recent record

```
select *
from reference_data.reference_data_novajunta A
where A.ts_inclusao IN 
  (select max(row2.ts_inclusao)
   from reference_data.reference_data_novajunta row2 
   where A.co_junta_comer = row2.co_junta_comer
     AND row2.co_informacao = A.co_informacao)
```

i'm getting the ERROR

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10002]: line 4:28 Invalid column reference 'co_junta_comer'`
```

Comment: To refer to the outer table in your inner subquery, you must use a correlated subquery.  That means using `exists`, as @zealous said.  This can be difficult in hive, there are [lots of restrictions](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.5/using-hiveql/content/hive_hive_subquery_limitations.html).

Comment: No need to do EXISTS, IN will work as well.

Comment: Does `select A.co_junta_comer from reference_data.reference_data_novajunta A` work?

Comment: @jarlh Yes exists. If column doesn't exist the error would be Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10002]: line 1:9 Invalid column reference 'co_junta_comer'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select rdn.*
from (select rdn.*,
             row_number() over (partition by co_junta_comer, co_informacao order by ts_inclusao desc) as seqnum
      from reference_data.reference_data_novajunta rdn
     ) rdn
where seqnum = 1;
```